# Bamboo - Create deployment trigger automatically when a new branch is created

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bamboo

I am using Bamboo and other Atlassian products for my CI/D workflow and would like to know about the following.

In Bamboo build plans, there is an option of creating a new plan branch when a new branch(in Atlassian stash) is created. I would like to know how to do the same for deployment. As of now, I have created triggers for my environment in the deployment project and I need to manually create a new "After successful build" trigger every time I create a new branch. Is there any configuration to automate this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to have deployment triggers from automatically created branches. You need to do this manually. Alternative solution to deploy the code from newly created branches would be to get rid off Deployment Project, and just add those tasks to build plan configuration itself. But of course this approach is not really flexible as Bamboo Deployment Project.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: Running on Bamboo version 6.2.1, still no such feature.

Comment: Atlassian products *shakes head*. They work ok until you actually try to implement a good workflow, then find there's a critical feature missing :( Thanks for confirming this and saving me ages trying to find out if it was possible! (on Bamboo 6.8.0 without it now too)

Comment: in Bamboo version 6.10 this feature still not exist